# How to track which site collection administrator has modified a user permission?

Tags: sharepoint-server

I have SharePoint 2013, in a site collection there is multiple site collection administrators
I don't know which site collection administrator changed the users permission from a document library or site access level.

can I track which site collection administrator changed a user permission in a document library or site level?